# Windows SourceTree + github でプッシュができない

Tags: github, sourcetree

コードをリモートのgithubにプッシュしようとしていますが、エラーが発生します。

[image: sourcetreeのエラー]

こちらのサイトを参考に手続きを設定を行いました。

[Windows+SourceTree+GithubではSSHログインを有効にしておこう](https://qiita.com/neon-izm/items/55de775dd50024403c5d)

※「最後にSourceTreeの認証をSSH経由にして、生成した鍵を使う」部分は手順が違うと思い、下記を参考しました。

[SourceTreeのGitHubへのSSH接続方法 for Windows 10](https://yu-report.com/entry/sourcetreessh/)

1. [ツール]→[SSHキーの作成／インポート]→[Generate]
2. 秘密キーと公開キーをファイル保存
3. Githubに公開キーを設定
4. SourceTree [全般]→[SSHクライアントの設定]に秘密鍵設定
5. Windows [Pagent Key List]に秘密鍵追加

以上の流れを行ったのですが、同じエラーがでてしまいます。
他に忘れていること、できることはあるでしょうか？

[image: githubに追加]
[image: Pagent Key Listに追加]
[image: sourctreeのアカウント設定]

Comment: https://jpdebug.com/p/2912098 の情報は確認されましたか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。こちらのサイトの方法で上手くいきました

Answer (score 2, accepted):

コメントでご紹介頂いた方法で解決しました。
[GitHubのパスワード認証廃止でSourcetreeで403エラーが発生して解決策がわからなかったのでまとめておく](https://jpdebug.com/p/2912098)

1. リポジトリの設定画面を開く
2. リモートリポジトリのパスを編集
3. `github.com` の前に `アクセストークン@` を追加
4. `https://[アクセストークン]@github.com/[ユーザ名]/[リポジトリ名].git`

以上です。